# ObjectDataSource direct binding

Tags: .net, objectdatasource

I have 2 SQL tables with a single relationship. 
Table A: Id, ApplicationID, Message.
Table B: Id, ApplicationName.
Relationship: A.ApplicationID = B.Id

I want to use a objectdatasource to bind them directly to a gridview but i want to show ApplicationName instead of ApplicationID.

How can i do that?

Thank U ALL.

Answer (score 0):

```
listbox.DataBindings.Add("ValueMember",DataSource ,"ApplicationID");
listbox.DisplayMember.Add("DisplayMember",DataSource,"ApplicationName");
```

On a TextBox or Label or what ever control, you can use `Tag` property to `"ValueMember"` and Text property as `DisplayMember` , or create your own.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of data access are you using? Ado.net? Linq2Sql? Entity Framework?

A sample would require data access which would query both tables and provide the data for the selectMethod of the object datasource.

Comment: Hi ScarTag, I've created a XSD DataSet and drag tables to it. Now i have representation of my sql tables inside the XSD but if i mess with the select query the XSD no longer map my entities. I have to call views instead?